# How to use $_POST or $_GET to filter data based on an HTML form

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms, airtable

I need to filter data on a website using an HTML form. I have the form made, and I know how to filter out a single data type.

Here's what the code looks like for the form:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
                <strong>Brand:</strong> <br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Input_1" value="Input 1"/> Input 1 <br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Input_2" value="Input 2"/> Input 2 <br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Input_3" value="Input 3"/> Input 3 <br>
</form>
```

And here's my code for the filtering system:

```
if($_POST['Input_1'] == "Input 1"){
        $query->addFilter("{Table Column}='Input 1'");
    }
elseif($_POST['Input_2'] == "Input 2"){
        $query->addFilter("{Table Column}='Input 2'");
    }
elseif($_POST['Input_3'] == "Input 3"){
        $query->addFilter("{Table Column}='Input 3'");
    }
```

The `addFilter` function is built in to the plugin I am using for Wordpress, and applies said filter to the Airtable database I am using. The criteria inside the `if` and `elseif` statements checks whether the box is ticked, and then applies whatever filter is specified to the data pulled in from the database.

The problem I am having is that I can only filter by one criteria, so for example if I check both Input 1 and Input 2, it only filters the most top level line of code and only filters the Input 1 items (which makes sense, since it reads that and does not need to go on to the next `elseif`).

What would be a better way to format this so that I can filter by a much more extensive criteria at the same time?

Comment: Am I missing the point or do you just need to change your `elseif`s to `if`s? Then the conditions are not mutually exclusive and all will be executed.

Comment: _“The addFilter function is built in to the plugin I am using for Wordpress”_ - well then you should probably start by checking the documentation for that, whether it allows filtering by multiple criteria in the first place, and if so, what the correct syntax would be to achieve this. (Edit: Unless what @Utkanos just said solves this already. Your problem description doesn’t make really make it clear ...)

Comment: @Utkanos That's what I tried originally, and it wasn't working - however it could have been a separate issue, so I'll try now that it works with `elseif`s

Comment: use only if condition in this format multiple filters will be add

Comment: if a checkbox isn't checked, it won't send anything. So maybe try: `if(isset($_POST['Input_1']))` for every checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly if your inputs are related I would make them an array of inputs:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Input[1]" value="Input 1"/> Input 1 <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Input[2]" value="Input 1"/> Input 1 <br>
```

Or perhaps more appropriately:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Input[myform][1]" value="Input 1"/> Input 1 <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Input[myform][2]" value="Input 1"/> Input 1 <br>
```

Once you have this you can now loop through your inputs one at a time:

```
foreach ($_GET['Input']['myform'] as $k => $v) {
    $query->addFilter("{Table Column}=".$v);
}
```

Note: This code is untested, but should provide the general idea.

Is this what you were looking for?